# Twig for loop stopping after two results (0, 1)

Tags: php, symfony, templates, twig, slim

I have a loop that is getting passed the following array via a slim view in PHP:

```
'breadcrumbs' => array(
    'path' => $breadcrumbs,
    'directory' => $breadcrumbDirectory
)
```

Both `$breadcrumbs` and `$breadcrumbDirectory` are arrays.

I am using the following loop to display the contents via Twig.

```
<li><a href="/panel">Home</a></li>
    {% for breadcrumb in breadcrumbs %}
        <li><a href="/panel/{{ breadcrumbs.directory[loop.index0] }}">{{ breadcrumbs.path[loop.index0] }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</li>
```

This code is working except it only displays the first 2 (0, 1) results. I am able to access indexes greater than 1 by calling `{{ breadcrumbs.path[2] }}` outside of the loop. Any help would be great, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop is incorrect, you need to loop one of the two arrays inside of it :

```
<li><a href="/panel">Home</a></li>
    {% for path in breadcrumbs['path'] %}
        <li><a href="/panel/{{ breadcrumbs.directory[loop.index0] }}">{{ path }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</li>
```

Comment: Shortly after posting this I figured that out. It's just one of those days :P.

Comment: I'll go ahead and accept your answer once I'm able to. Thanks.

Comment: No problem :-) glad you've spotted it yourself afterwards :-)